# Data adapter troubles

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledbdataadapter

When I run the code the line which filled my datatable says that there is no value given for one or more parameters

```vb
Order = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE 
Driver_ID = " & ID, DBREF)
Order.Fill(dataODtable)
DGVorders.DataSource = dataODtable
```

The code says this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

Below is an image link to the database and table it is referencing.
(Database orders table)

[image]

If I try run the code without the where statement it runs without crashing.

Comment: Use parameters... `Driver_ID = '" & ID & "'"` enclose id with ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field DRIVER_ID is clearly a string, as such you need single quotes around the value you want to use for the WHERE clause.
But that would be wrong for a long list of reasons (Sql Injection, Parsing errors, automatic type conversion with incompatible locales).

So you really need to start using parameterized queries as soon as possible to avoid these misteps

```
Dim cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Driver_ID = @drvID"
Order = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmdText, DBREF)
Order.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@drvID", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = ID
Order.Fill(dataODtable)
DGVorders.DataSource = dataODtable
```

Now the query is no more built concatenating together strings pieces (the main source for sql injection hacks) but you create a parameter object of the correct type and pass it to the database engine that will use it when needed.
Another benefit is the more clear code you get. In this case perhaps is not very evident but with more complex queries you will have a more clear understanding of what you are asking to do to the database.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice on how to make my code more presentable. I really need to work on that. Just one question i just started of SQL and I want to know what the function order.selectcommand.parameters.add() does?

Comment: When you create the adapter it takes the command text and build an OleDbCommand object under the property SelectCommand. This command receives the query text and you can add Parameters to it. Parameters values are used by the database engine when a parameter placeholder is present in the query text (The @something). Additional rules are in place for OleDb but in your simple case they don't matter.

Comment: This pattern allows you to avoid complex string concatenations in the command text (with all the possible errors) and removes any Sql Injection path, while, at the same time, you could be precise in what you pass to the database engine. When you step up to more powerful engines (Sql Server, Oracle) they can use this pattern to optimize the code needed to retrieve your data and achieve higher scalability in the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
Order = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE 
Driver_ID = '"& ID &"'", DBREF)
Order.Fill(dataODtable)
DGVorders.DataSource = dataODtable
```

maybe this will be the problem.

Comment: That fixed it. I feel kinda gutted it was such a simple fix and i didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

if `Driver_ID` is alphanumeric column, select query should be `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Driver_ID = '" & ID & "' ;"`